# How to generate random numbers using only specific digits, e.g [1234] [4213] [3124]

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

In VB.NET I am trying to figure out how exactly to generate numbers of a fixed length using specific digits.

I have seen these questions but they do not cover what I am looking for:
[How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)
  [Produce a random number in a range using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975290/produce-a-random-number-in-a-range-using-c-sharp)
[How to generate random number with the specific length in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673385/how-to-generate-random-number-with-the-specific-length-in-python)
[Generating an array of random strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144346/generating-an-array-of-random-strings)
[Generation 9 digits random number including leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253157/generation-9-digits-random-number-including-leading-zero)

I am trying to generate 4 digit numbers using *only* 1, 2, 3, and 4.
It would be like this:

```
1234  
2134  
3124  
2143  
2431  
2413
```

etc...
Can someone explain to me how this can be achieved?

Comment: Generate only specific random digits and concatenate these.

Comment: up, unless they can occur only once, but that wouldn't be random.

Comment: is "1111" legal?  otherwise the pool is pretty small, you can type them in and just shuffle them

Comment: random.next(1,4)*1000 + random.next(1,4)*100 + random.next(1,4)*10 + random.next(1,4)

Comment: @Jeremy `Random` **or** `System.Random`? :)

Comment: @Codexer see my answer. System is usually included so you don't need to specify the package name.

Comment: Correct Claudius, the numbers can only appear once.

Comment: If this question is answered, please click the checkmark to move it off the Unanswered list; that also helps others find good answers when they search.

Answer (score 4):

As the comments note, the post leaves open several questions.  As it stands there is not really much to do with `Random`.  *It sounds like* you want `N` values made from those four digits, using each one once.   The starting point this [`Permutation` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21090635/1070452)  from a great answer by Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå to create a list of the combinations of the digits (be sure to upvote it).

```
Dim Combos = Permutation.Create("1234".ToCharArray())

Dim intVals = Combos.ConvertAll(Of Int32)(Function(s) Int32.Parse(s)).
            OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next()).
            ToArray()
```

- The first part gets the combination of 24 element, then
- converts the result to integer
- then randomizes the order and puts it in an array.

If you didn't mean "values" but strings (referring to values having a length sounds more like strings of numerals), just skip the `ConvertAll` step.  If you only need a few, you can add `.Take(5)` after `OrderBy` to grab only 5 (for example).

Personally, since there *are* only 24 possible (non repeating) combinations, I'd paste them into the code as an array and use that as the starting point unless the "1234" part is dynamic.

See also:

- [permutation of string. permutation or combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21084651/1070452)
- [Calculating Permutations](http://www.bearcave.com/random_hacks/permute.html)

Comment: I created an empty solution and added the Permutation class and your code, but it says that RNG is not declared.

Comment: `RNG` would be a `Random`: `Private RNG As New Random()`

Answer (score -1):

This will generate a number using the min and max (1 - 4) provided of the length provided (4) as a String. If you need to use the Integer, of course, you'll have to do that casting after it's generated. There could also be something funky that happens if the min < 0 and max > 9, of course.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim min As Integer = 1
    Dim max As Integer = 4

    Dim length As Integer = 4


    Dim ranNumFinal As String = ""

    Static generator As System.Random = New System.Random()

    For i = 1 To length
        If i = 1 Then 'First time around
            ranNumFinal = generator.Next(min, max + 1).ToString
        Else
            ranNumFinal = ranNumFinal.ToString & generator.Next(min, max + 1).ToString
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(ranNumFinal)
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

```
    Dim r As New Random
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Debug.WriteLine(r.Next(1, 5) * 1000 + r.Next(1, 5) * 100 + r.Next(1, 5) * 10 + r.Next(1, 5))

    Next
```

Comment: `r.Next(1, 4)` will produce a value 1-3 - the last param is exclusive.  It also doesnt address whether digits can repeat (which we do not know).  Not my DV, BTW

Comment: @Plutonix was just about to fix it

Comment: @Plutonix plus we didn't get a full spec :)

Comment: I know.  I hate when people drop off partially defined questions like so much dirty laundry to be picked up later.  Your post also doesnt account for dupes

Comment: @Plutonix a poor question does not warrant a downvoted answer that meets the initial question

Comment: **I do not DV anything I comment on** ever

Comment: @Plutonix OK thanks. must have been someone else. thanks.

Comment: I said that in the first comment when it appeared

Comment: @Plutonix I didn't understand what that meant at the time